# How to debug current module(with -m argument) in vscode?

Tags: python, vscode-debugger

My test files have some `explicit relative import`, when i directly run debug, it will raise exception(because the exists of relative import),
so i want to use `-m` argument when using debug mode in vscode.

I want to dubug multiple file in `project_test` with -m argument(this will allow me to use relative imoprt)

I have tried to modify the launch.json file, but it seems only allow me to specify a fixed module name,
how can i do this?

```
project_test
├── log_test.py
├── user_test.py
├── other_test.py
```

the last two lines are my attempts.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            # "module": "project_test.log_test"  # this works correctly
            "module": "project_test.${file}"     # this will raise exception

        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the following config will allow me to debug all files without specify a fixed name.
The key point is to set the module path correctly.

```py
# launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            // "module": "$('mytest.')${file}"
            "module": "project_test.${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
        }
    ]
}
```

More info at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference